# calculated field in Excel Pivot

Tags: excel, pivot-table, excel-2016

I am pretty sure that what I want to do is not possible, but I thought I'd give the experts a try.

I have a pivot table with countries in rows, date in columns and kgs, acreage and yield in rows. I am trying to make an estimation using calculated fields. What I want is (current)acreage*(previous date)yield. 
Kind of a modified "Show As" calculation. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that columns A-D are Date; Kgs; Acreage and Yield respectively and row 1 contains the labels, why not use a formula in column E.

As row 2 contains the first valid data, you would have to start at row 3.  Therefore, cell E3 should contain the formula `=C3*D2` which should be copied down to the last row of the pivot table.

Comment: Kgs, acreage and yield are subcolumns. I have a group of them for each date. Maybe I wasn't spesific enough on my post. So I want to multiple the most recent kgs with the previous yield. I have added a column next to the pivot for noe, and a small macro to help with formatting, I was just wondering if there was a wayvto make a foeld like that in pivot cause it's not the forst time I need it.